# mysql imported model forward engineer error

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have created a small db with 3 tables in MySQL Workbench. After creating a table I've inserted some data into it, and it works fine. Now i have another pc. I exported the model as a mwb file from the first pc and i want to import that mwb file to my 2nd pc. Here is the error i get while importing the model (forward engineering) to my 2nd pc. I don't understand why the model created in MySQL Workbench doesn't work in another pc's workbench. Can someone help? Thank you.[mwb file codes i wanted to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUhsE.png)

[errors i got when forward engineering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur0Rt.png)

Edit: This is the script that gives error now :

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering
    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Schema mydb
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Schema karakoyd
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Schema karakoyd
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `karakoyd` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci ;
    USE `karakoyd` ;

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `karakoyd`.`emp`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `karakoyd`.`emp` (
      `idemp`  NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `pass` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `salt` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
      `log` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `rütbe` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idemp`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `idemployee_UNIQUE` (`idemp` ASC) VISIBLE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 19
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    COLLATE = utf8_turkish_ci;
```

Comment: Add text instead of images.

Comment: Minimized, we don't need all of it.

Comment: @VBoka i've synchronized model. now it only gives error on my emp table. emp table doesn't have blob or image column so i don't think the problem is from images but thank you for response

Comment: @OğuzcanŞirolu i do not think you understand me. In your question you have given us images to work with. What should we do with this images ? Retype all of the code to see where is the error ? Copy and paste the script here and do not upload images to us. Also, as jarlh wrote: give us only the part of the script that does not work.

Comment: Oh okay i am going to do that now. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Hi @OğuzcanŞirolu great, also please add the MySQL version from first and from second pc.

Comment: *`idemp`  NOT NULL,* - datatype is lost.

Comment: @VBoka they are both 8.0.19 i checked them now

Comment: @Akina i'll change it. i'll write the result thx.
edit: i checked it. it is not the problem becouse other tables primary key's are created same way and they are works fine. thank you for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, in your images, you can not create columns in your tables without defining the type of the column.

For example in your table `EMP` you are creating it like this:

```
idemp not null
```

and it should be like this(just for example):

```
idemp int not null
```

[here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93e23ea977ead028b9ad5c434c967c6a)

[And a new demo with your table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f3b21ba27085c8e267f77c4ebcd567d)

This is how your TABLE code should look like.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `karakoyd`.`emp` (
      `idemp` int NOT NULL,   --the change was made here(column's data type was missing)
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `pass` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `salt` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
      `log` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `rütbe` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idemp`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `idemployee_UNIQUE` (`idemp` ASC) VISIBLE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 19
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    COLLATE = utf8_turkish_ci;
```